# SceneKit: Programmatically use "Procedural Sky" option from Scene Inspector?

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit, augmented-reality, scnscene

In the Xcode SceneKit Scene Inspector, there is a `Procedural Sky` option under the `Environment` section.

According to some tutorials, enabling this option will impart more realism to 3D models.

1) If you're creating a scene from code and not from the Scene Inspector, how do you enable the `Procedural Sky` option? There is no `Environment` property.

2) Does the `Procedural Sky` option only work if you using PBR materials?

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: @Paresh.P See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can: The class you are looking for is [MDLSkyCubeTexture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlskycubetexture)

The most basic way to use it to put it into your scene's background contents:

```
class MyGameScene: SCNScene {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.background.contents = MDLSkyCubeTexture(name: "sky",
                                          channelEncoding: .float16,
                                        textureDimensions: vector_int2(128, 128),
                                                turbidity: 0,
                                             sunElevation: 1.5,
                                upperAtmosphereScattering: 0.5,
                                             groundAlbedo: 0.5)
        // To let the sky influence the lighting:
        self.lightingEnvironment.contents = self.background.contents
    }
}
```

You'll have to read up on the parameters yourself since I just stumbled over this.

I found these links of interest:

- https://github.com/FlexMonkey/SkyCubeTextureDemo
- http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/07/a-first-look-at-model-ios-sky-cube.html

These sources are 5 years old, so I'm sure some stuff has changed meanwhile.

Regarding the second part of your question: You can pipe this into your materials, but I'm not too knowledgeable yet.

Comment: Works very well on Xcode 11, iOS 13! Using values above create colors different from the default procedural sky colors, but links provided & Xcode documentation shows how to create dusk, noon, etc.

Answer (score -1):

For iOS 12 use:

```
configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
```

Comment: This can be set when using ARKit, but not for the basic SceneKit Scene.